# What is lock pinger in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Can somebody explain me what is lock pinger in MongoDB

> [LockPinger] cluster XXXXXXX:27019 pinged successfully at Wed Feb  5
>   04:46:01 2014 by distributed lock pinger
>   'XXXXXX:27019/ip-XX-XX-XX-XX:27017:1391512883:1804289383', sleeping
>   for 30000ms

Answer (score 2):

There are distributed locks used in a sharded environment.  The balancer [takes a lock](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharding-balancing/#cluster-balancer) (only one migration is active at a time), the shards will take out meta data locks when doing splits also.  Those live in the [config.locks](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/config-database/#config.locks) collection.

As for the lock pinger, the [config.lockpings](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/config-database/#config.lockpings) collection keeps track of the active components in the cluster, so it is an informational collection.  The lock pinger is what populates this collection and you have pasted what looks to be the result of a successful ping.

Note: please do not use these collections for anything in your application or elsewhere.  These collections (as noted on the linked pages) are considered internal only and can (and will) be changed/removed/updated without notice.

Comment: Can you please explain me what is actually happening when doing lock pinging?

Comment: As I said, it is keeping track of the various pieces of the cluster, when a process successfully pings it updates the timestamp in the collection, then the pinger goes back to sleep (as you can see in the log message).  Perhaps if you explained why you are trying to figure this out it might be easier to answer your question, in general terms this can just be considered internal housekeeping my MongoDB and be ignored.

Comment: The reason is, I have created shard cluster with 3 shard servers, 1 config and 1 router. While monitoring all the servers the router sometimes use 100% of CPU but I do not see any log regarding high CPU usage. So I thought that this lock pinging may use high CPU for pinging process. Please advise me if there is any other reason for 100% CPU usage.

Comment: It will not be the lock pings, they are very lightweight, I assume you think they are the culprit because they show up regularly, but that is just a function of them running periodically (people often think the serverStatus command is at fault on mongod processes for the same reason).  If you are seeing high CPU, then I would look for large in memory sorts, hash computation on a hashed shard key, see if increasing the log level on the mongos gives more insight.  Oh, and if this is a prod system, do not run with 1 config server, ever.

Comment: Thank you.. Do you know any other reason behind the high CPU usage?

Comment: I think this is not going to be possible to answer properly in these comments, I listed a couple of possibilities, but really you need to post details in a new question about the CPU usage.  I would include things like the nature of the CPU usage (system, user, attributed to the mongos or not), how memory usage and IO usage looks and whether the high CPU correlates with any particular activity.  A graph would be nice to see the trend, and then as I said you may need to increase the log level to get the activity correlation

Comment: Ok, I will do as you suggested. Thank you..

Comment: I have posted an question with CPU Usage graph.